# ¿Cómo creo una función que lea un archivo .txt y acumule los caracteres en un diccionario python?

Tags: python

La pregunta es esta:
*Crear una función leer_libro que tendrá como entrada el nombre del archivo donde hemos guardado el libro.
Esta función leerá el archivo línea a línea, y llamará a cada línea la función contar_caracteres y
actualizar el diccionario acumulando los nuevos valores. Una vez leído todo el libro, se devolverá
el diccionario con los valores finales*

La función de contar_caracteres ya la he definido(solo sirve para ir llenando el diccionario y saber cuantas veces se repite dicho caracter)

El problema es que solo puedo llenar el diccionario con la primera linea y no acumula los demás valores del libro.
De momento tengo este codigo, si alguien me ayudara le estaría muy agradecido.

````
 fitxer=input("Nombre del fichero: ")
 def leer_libro(fichero):
     #Lo abrimos para leer
     with open(fichero,'r') as CountingFile:
         lineas=0
         caracteres=0
         for line in CountingFile.readlines(): 
             lineas=lineas+1 
             caracteres_por_linea=contar_caracteres(linea)  #diccionario
             caracteres_totales=caracteres+len(linea) # cantidad de caracteres totales```
 
```print("Línies: {}\ncaracteres por linea: {}\nCaracteres totales {}".format(lineas,caracteres_por_linea,caracteres_totales)) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Una solución:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def leer_libro(fichero):
    cuenta_caracteres = defaultdict(int)

    with open(fichero, 'r') as CountingFile:
        for line in CountingFile.readlines():
            for caracter in line:
                cuenta_caracteres[caracter] += 1

    return cuenta_caracteres
```

Primero, contar los caracteres en una función separada (que no muestras) no parece funcionar; necesitas un diccionario que no vemos por ninguna parte y, a fin de cuentas, es demasiada complicación para algo que se puede hacer con una simple instrucción.

`defaultdict` es un diccionario al que le puedes indicar un valor por default: si tratas de acceder a una clave que no existe, el diccionario automáticamente crea una clave y la inicializa según el tipo declarado. En este caso,

```
cuenta_caracteres = defaultdict(int)
```

el default es cero pues el tipo es `int`.

Luego sólo me queda recorrer el archivo contando caracter por caracter.

Uno de los caracteres encontrados es '\n', por lo que no necesito llevar la cuenta de las líneas por separado; basta imprimir las ocurrencias de '\n'.

#### Demo

Texto: El Quijote de la Mancha.

Código:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def leer_libro(fichero):
    cuenta_caracteres = defaultdict(int)

    with open(fichero, 'r') as CountingFile:
        for line in CountingFile.readlines():
            for caracter in line:
                cuenta_caracteres[caracter] += 1

    return cuenta_caracteres

cuenta = leer_libro("quijote.txt")
print("Archivo tiene ", cuenta['\n'], " lineas")
for k, v in cuenta.items():
    print(f"Caracter {k}: {v} ocurrencias")
```

produce:

```
Archivo tiene  37570  lineas
Caracter 
: 37570 ocurrencias
Caracter E: 1538 ocurrencias
Caracter l: 88392 ocurrencias
Caracter  : 355394 ocurrencias
Caracter i: 78285 ocurrencias
Caracter n: 108671 ocurrencias
Caracter g: 17183 ocurrencias
Caracter e: 222286 ocurrencias
Caracter o: 154315 ocurrencias
Caracter s: 123176 ocurrencias
Caracter h: 20030 ocurrencias
Caracter d: 85728 ocurrencias
Caracter a: 192412 ocurrencias
Caracter Q: 2649 ocurrencias

...

Caracter 9: 9 ocurrencias
Caracter %: 1 ocurrencias
Caracter @: 1 ocurrencias
Caracter $: 2 ocurrencias

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: En realidad, defaultdict no crea el valor default segun el tipo que le ingreses. Citando [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.__missing__): "Si default_factory no es None, se llama sin argumentos para proporcionar un valor predeterminado para la llave dada, este valor se inserta en el diccionario para la llave y se retorna."

Comment: se determina el valor inicial de default_factory con el primer argumento de defaultdict. Y como dice en esa seccion de la documentación, default_factory se llama sin argumentos. Es decir, espera un callable! Lo que pasa es que si llamas a int sin argumentos, devuelve 0. Algo perfectamente valido (lo probé y funciona) es `defaultdict(lambda:10)`.

Comment: También cabe recalcar que es mejor iterar directamente sobre el objeto que representa al archivo en lugar de usar readlines. Me confirmé esto a mi mismo con [esta pagina](altaruru.com/como-leer-un-archivo-de-texto-linea-a-linea-desde-python/)

Answer (score 0):

```
def leer_libro(fichero):
    cont = 0        #   contador de lineas
    letras = {}     #   diccionario con los caracteres

    with open(fichero, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for linea in f:
            cont += 1
            linea = linea.replace(" ", "").lower()  #   Quito espacios y paso a minúsculas
            dic_aux = contar_caracteres(linea)      #   Llamo a la función que devuelve un diccionario

            for letra in dic_aux:   #   Añado los datos recibidos al diccionario de caracteres
                letras[letra] = letras[letra] + 1 if letra in letras else 1
    return cont, letras     #   devuelvo el número de lineas y el diccionario


def contar_caracteres(linea):
    caracteres = {}
    for car in linea:       #   Recorro la linea y cuento los caracteres
        caracteres[car] = caracteres[car] + 1 if car in caracteres else 1
    return caracteres   #   devuelvo el diccionario completo
```

Llamadas a las funciones

```
nom_fich = "archivo.txt"    

n_lineas, datos = leer_libro((nom_fich))

print('Num de lineas ', n_lineas)
print('Num. de caracteres diferentes', len(datos))
print('Total de caracteres ', sum(datos.values()))

for k, v in datos.items():
    print(f"Caracter {k}: {v} ocurrencias")
```

Comment: Este código lo haía preparado ayer antes de caerme internet. Mucho más bonita la propuesta de Candid Moe

Comment: Aun así, esta bueno tener a mano una alternativa sin usar modulos c: Lo unico que cambiaría de tu código es esto `''.join(linea.split())` por esto: `linea.replace(" ", "")` que reemplaza cada espacio que encuentra por una cadena vacía.

Comment: Modificado. Me liaba la posiilidad de varios espacios seguidos, me despistó con `strip()` con varios espacios

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar a [la respuesta de @CandidMoe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/500332/158880), quería aclarar una cosa y ofrecer una versión que ocupa mucha menos memoria a la hora de leer las líneas del archivo basado en el código que el ofrece.

#### Sobre el primer argumento de defaultdict

Primero que nada: En realidad, defaultdict no crea el valor default segun el tipo que le ingreses. Citando la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.__missing__):

> Si default_factory no es None, se llama sin argumentos para
> proporcionar un valor predeterminado para la llave dada, este valor se
> inserta en el diccionario para la llave y se retorna.

Se determina el valor inicial de default_factory con el primer argumento de defaultdict. Y como dice en esa seccion de la documentación, default_factory se llama sin argumentos. Es decir, espera un callable (un objeto al cual le pongas parentesis a la derecha y haga algo, como una función)! Lo que pasa es que si llamas a int sin argumentos, devuelve 0.
Algo perfectamente valido (lo probé y funciona) es `defaultdict(lambda:10)`

#### Una versión optimizada

```
from collections import defaultdict

def leer_libro(fichero):
    cuenta_caracteres = defaultdict(int)

    with open(fichero, 'r') as CountingFile:
        # notese que quité el .readlines e itero directamente sobre el archivo.
        # de esa manera evito cargar todo el contenido del archivo en la memoria.
        for line in CountingFile:
            for caracter in line:
                cuenta_caracteres[caracter] += 1

    return cuenta_caracteres

cuenta = leer_libro("quijote.txt")
print("Archivo tiene ", cuenta['\n'], " lineas")
for k, v in cuenta.items():
    print(f"Caracter {k}: {v} ocurrencias")
```

Al menos, iterar directamente sobre el archivo es, según esta pagina, la mejor opción: altaruru.com/como-leer-un-archivo-de-texto-linea-a-linea-desde-python/ (SO no me toma el link).